# Creating a query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I need to create a query that returns all customers from (State QLD) their firstName, lastName. And products purchased - productName, category, price, and stock availability but not productID. I can create simple queries but nothing that is this complex.

```
-Orders( orderID, ordertypeID, customerID, quantity, purchasedate)

-Customers( customer_ID, state, postcode, street_Number, street_Address, customer_Ln, customer_Fn)

-Order_Contents( orderID, productID, quantity)

-Products( product_ID, product_Category, product_Name,  product_Description, unit_Price, in_Stock)

-Categories( categoryName, employeeID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do a simple JOIN with the tables like below

```
select c.customer_Ln, c.customer_Fn,
p.product_Category, p.product_Name,  
p.product_Description, p.unit_Price, p.in_Stock
from customers c 
left join orders o on c.customerID = o.customerID
left join Order_Contents oc on o.orderID = oc.orderID
left join Products p on p.productID = oc.productID
where c.State = 'QLD';
```

Comment: All customers, not just the ones with orders

Comment: @Shadow, in that case change it to outer join. I believe OP means customer names.